# angularjs watch is still being called after deregisterWatch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I'm getting a very weird behavior and I would like to know if this is the expected one or something should be changed. I have a controller with the following piece of code:

See demo here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cqofLqwm/

```
UserSvc.refreshCyclic(20 * 1000);
$scope.$on('userchanged', function onUserChanged(event, user) {
  stopWatchScopeUser();
  $scope.model.user = user;
  watchScopeUser();
});

function watchScopeUser() {
  stopWatchScopeUser = $scope.$watch('model.user', function scopeUserChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      console.log('user changed');
    }
  }, true);
}

watchScopeUser();
```

`UserSvc.refreshCyclic` gets the user from server every 20 sec., and checks for `user` object changes. If there are changes, it raises `userchanged` event.

What is happening here is that even after calling `stopWatchScopeUser()`, when assigning `user` to `$scope.model.user`, the watch expression is called with `newValue` equal to `oldValue`, both to the most recent user. (So the condition `newValue !== oldValue` fails).

If I comment `stopWatchScopeUser` then the `scopeUserChanged` is called but `newValue` is different than `oldValue`.

It's quite strange that after detaching the watch on `model.user`, it is still being called. Is this the normal behavior or there is something incorrect? What should I do to definitely deatach watch listener?

Comment: That is because you are registering a new watch again on the next line.

Comment: Hmm.. so you mean that this is because of inital watch? Would that mean that `$scope.model.user = user` is not triggering the watch, but watchScopeUser()?

Comment: When you register a watch it will trigger it once for the first time to get the current value for later digest's dirty check

Comment: You're right, thanks! If you post it as a solution I will accept that.